# Do I need an "explicit" identity morphism to have a category?

Tags: category-theory, directed-graphs, monomorphisms

I'm trying to study category theory as an autodidact, using Bartosz Milewski's *Category Theory
for Programmers*, and I've just finished chapter 1, where the last question/exercises is whether *a directed graph is a category*.

So looking at a simple graph example as [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Directed.svg/1280px-Directed.svg.png), where there are no arrows connecting a point *directly* to itself.

But is that necessary? I'd say no, as I can compose the other non-identity morphisms (one is actually not even necessary, the counter-clockwise arrow) to get all of the three identity morphisms.

So, I thought that a directed graph is a category if I can reach any point from any point, as that seems to me as a sufficient condition for being able to write an identity morphism for each of the points.

Comment: In the picture the horizontal arrow and the arrow from up-right to down should give rise by composition to an arrow from up-left to down. But such arrow lacks. Btw, if you start with a directed graph then you can construct a category by taking *paths* (a sequence of "consecutive" edges) as arrows and adding identity arrows.

Comment: A directed graph **isn't** a category. Rather a directed graph **gives rise to** a category, whose morphisms are the (directed) paths in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention I stick to firmly is that questions like "is a directed graph a category" are meaningless; it's neither true nor false, the question is just ungrammatical. You can see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/the-type-system-of-mathematics/) awhile ago for examples and discussion of other ungrammatical questions in mathematics.

Here is a simpler example to understand: the question "is a set a group" is also meaningless, because being a group is a structure, not a property. The definition of a group breaks up into two bits: a group is a collection of *data* subject to some *axioms*, and the meaningful way to ask "is $X$ a group" is for $X$ to be a collection of the appropriate data for which you are being asked to check the axioms, namely

- a set $X$,
- a candidate multiplication $m : X^2 \to X$, and
- a candidate identity $e : 1 \to X$.

You might call such a tuple $(X, m, e)$ a *pregroup*; then it's meaningful / grammatically correct to ask whether a pregroup is a group, since satisfying the group axioms is a *property* of a pregroup.

It is similarly meaningless to ask whether a directed graph is a category. The definition of a category again breaks up into two bits, a bunch of data subject to a bunch of axioms, and again the meaningful way to ask "is $C$ a category" is for $C$ to be a collection of the appropriate data for which you are being asked to check the axioms, namely

- a collection $C_1$ of candidate morphisms and a collection $C_0$ of candidate objects,
- candidate source and target maps $s, t : C_1 \to C_0$,
- a candidate composition map $\circ : C_1 \times_{C_0} C_1 \to C_1$ (leaving the source and target maps needed to write the pullback implicit), and
- candidate identity morphisms $\text{id} : C_0 \to C_1$.

And again you might call such a tuple $(C_1, C_0, s, t, \circ, \text{id})$ a *precategory*, and then it's meaningful / grammatically correct to ask whether a precategory is a category, since satisfying the category axioms is a *property* of a precategory.

A directed graph does *not* supply the necessary data for a precategory; it consists at best of candidates for $C_1$ (the edges), $C_0$ (the vertices), and $s, t$ (the source and target maps identifying the endpoints of the edges), but contains no candidates for either composition or identity morphisms. This is true whether or not there *exist* such candidates (and there generally won't); every set admits at least one group structure but I still maintain that this does not imply that the answer to "is a set a group" is "yes."

Comment: I the subscript $C_0$ a typo in the second to last bullet point?

Comment: @Enrico: it is not. It denotes a pullback (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory) ), which concretely encodes the fact that composition is only defined for morphisms whose sources and targets match. There are other ways to write down the category axioms that don't do this explicitly but this is the one with the most direct comparison to directed graphs.

Comment: I think I'm able to follow your answer up to the second to last paragraph, but I have some doubts about the very last one. You write that "_A_ directed graph does not supply...", which means that what follow apply to any graph, and not to the one in my example. Which also means that I cannot make any changes to it to make it "supply...". Why drawing all the possible 9 arrows between three points would not be enough? Wouldn't the three arrows going from each point to itself candidates for identity morphisms?

Comment: @Enrico: you are talking about whether a directed graph can be *given* a category structure. Again, my convention is that this question is a completely different question from the question of whether a directed graph *is* a category. Some directed graphs can be given a category structure (two necessary conditions are the existence of self-loops and transitivity in the sense that if there exists a directed edge $a \to b$ and a directed edge $b \to c$ there must exist a directed edge $a \to c$) and most can't, but even the ones that can *aren't categories*.

Comment: You say you're reading a book for programmers so here is a more programming-flavored way to say it: to say that something is a category means that that something is a construction of an object of a class called "category," and the constructor of that class takes certain inputs, namely the data I've described above. You cannot call the constructor function on a directed graph because you haven't supplied enough of the inputs! Once you've supplied enough of the inputs what you have is more than a directed graph, it's a precategory.

Comment: No, I still don't get it. The graph has no morphisms, as you say, right? It has some "graphical" arrows. Which can be tought of as _candidate_ morphisms, if the aim is to give the graph a category structure. If a category requires, among the other things, identity morphisms, then it does make a difference if the graph has "self-loops" or not. And I can think of a graph which has all the arrows that it needs to have a candidate for each of those requirements of the category. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: with reference to programming, I can construct an object of a class from an object of another class, if I tell the compiler how to interpet each bit of the latter in a way that is needed for the former

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112941/discussion-between-enrico-maria-de-angelis-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: @Enrico: it does make a difference. A category requires identity morphisms and your directed graph doesn't have self-loops. You can add them but then you're looking at a *different* directed graph. More generally, you can construct a category out of any directed graph by taking the "free category" on it, where you formally adjoin identity morphisms and compositions (so the morphisms are paths in the original graph, possibly of length zero). This category has an underlying directed graph which is a *different graph* from the one you started with; it is *not the same object* as the original.

Comment: In programming terms, I of course can construct objects of a class from objects of another class in all sorts of ways but that doesn't let me say that objects of one class *are* objects of another. There are many such constructions and they aren't unique and I have to specify which one I'm using.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a better grasp on this now. Thank you. And I hope you'll keep an eye on this _category-theory_ tag, as I'll likely add many other questions.

Comment: Qiaochu, given the view of yours that you have show in your answer, I'd be curious to know what you think of the book _Categories for the working mathematician_ by Mac Lane.

Answer (score 3):

Your example has a class (in fact, set) of objects: the three blue dots (I call them $1,2,3$ in the obvious order in the image.

For every two objects $a,b$, you have a (candidate) set of morphisms: the set of arrows from $a$ to $b$. Note that this set is empty for several pairs, e.g., there is no morphism from $2$ to $1$ and no morphism from $1$ to $3$. No problem, that's okay and happens eben in the best categories. But there is also no ("explicit") morphism from any object to itself.
Nor do we have a law of *composition*: Two arrows together do not make an arrow.

So in order to speak of a category, we *must* define the set of morphisms from $a$ to $b$ differently. It somewhat suggests itself to take the set of *walks* from $a$ to $b$ as set of morphisms. This solves all problems we have automatically:

- We have the *empty walk* from $a$ to $a$ as identity morphism. (Even though all three empty walks are the same, we should still distinguish them by their varying "starting" and "end" points).
- We have a law of composition: A walk from $a$ to $b$ followed by a walk from $b$ to $c$ is a walk from $a$ to $c$.
- We verify that composition is associative and that empty walks do indeed behave as identities (i.e., neutral under composition)

An even more sophisticated choice of morphisms might be to take all walks modulo an equivalence relation where going along a double-arrow and immediately back cancels (i.e., the two directions of such an arrow are inverses). This works, but showing associativity of composition requires a bit more care.

If we had an *explicit* arrow $1\to 1$, say, then the walk $1\to 1\to 2$ would not be the same walk as $1\to 2$ alone, i.e., $1\to 1$ would *not* act as identity. We'd still have only the empty walk act as identity!

Comment: If I correctly understand your  third paragrah, you are saying that we are free to choose the word _morphism_ to mean a sequence of tip-to-tail arrows. This way we can choose those arrows in order to have the morphisms that we need for that set of points to be a category. And you also say that doing so solves all problems. And you also say that we can throw away some "redundant" sequence of arrows. Then I don't understand what point you are making in the last paragraph. Can you please help me understand it?